# Mock a package that survives from ... import

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

In a test case, I want to mock the `keras` package where I will not know how the user will going to import that package. This means I need to support

```py
import keras
from keras import something
from keras.backend import otherthings
from keras.sub.subsub....module  import somethingelse
```

I tried to use a `Mock` object to do the following:

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock
m = Mock()
sys.modules['keras'] = m

import keras                # Success
from keras import backend   # Success
from keras.backend import a # Failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.backend'; 'keras' is not a package
```

I can certainly add a line like

```
sys.modules['keras.backend'] = m
```

to bypass this error, but I would not know if a user would want another module tomorrow - and I will just have to add in the list of modules, which does not seem to be a good choice.

Is there any approach that I can mock this module *recursively* ?

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would be to patch the built-in [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#import__) function with a wrapper that returns a mock object if the given name starts with `'keras'`:

```
import builtins
from unittest.mock import Mock

def mock_keras(name, *args, mocks={}, orig_import=__import__, **kwargs):
    if name.split('.')[0] == 'keras':
        return mocks.setdefault(name, Mock(name=name))
    return orig_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
builtins.__import__ = mock_keras

import keras
from keras.foo import bar

print(keras)
print(bar)
```

This outputs:

```
<Mock name='keras' id='22749078475248'>
<Mock name='keras.foo.bar' id='22749077888256'>
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/SPC0mh